# Null items in js array are appearing on my set interval loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, setinterval

```
let arrayA=[1,2,"",3,""]
console.log(arrayA);

arrayA= arrayA.filter((item) => item !== "");
console.log(arrayA);

const loopArray = () => {
    counter++;
    if (counter == arrayA.length) {
        counter = 0;
    }
    if (arrayA[counter] !== "") {
        arrayID.innerHTML=array[counter];
}

loopQuotes();
setInterval(loopArray,5500);
```

When my loop is being displayed, it shows extends the prior item before the `""`. So instead of looping 1, 2, and 3 for 5 seconds each what happens is 1 gets 5 seconds, while 2 and 3 get 10 seconds.

How do I make it consistent that each of them gets 5 seconds each? Even if say I add and remove stuff from the array consistently?

I am using vanilla JS.

Comment: what is `loopQuotes` and `counter` ?

Comment: Other than not declaring `counter`, and fixing a typo `array[counter]` in your `loopArray` function, [your code works properly](https://jsfiddle.net/kzh4m6be/). You should probably add `counter++` to end of that function too otherwise it starts at 1 rather than zero.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arrayA = [1,2,"",3,""].filter((item) => item !== "");


const loopArray = arr => {
  let counter = 0;
  return () => arrayID.innerHTML=arr[counter++ % arr.length];      
}

setInterval(loopArray(arrayA),250);
```

```html
<div id=arrayID>
```